# Login failure with grails ldap configuration

Tags: spring, grails, active-directory

I've configured grails ldap plugin as follows in application.yml and added dependencies of spring security core and ldap in build.gradle.
grails:
   plugin:
      springsecurity:

```
     providerNames: ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider'] 
     ldap:
        context:
           managerDn: "CN=ldapreader_website,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com"
           managerPassword: '[secret]'
           server: 'ldap://mydomain.com:389/'
        authorities:
           groupSearchBase: '[CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com]'
           groupSearchFilter: 'member={0}'
        search:
           base: '[CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com]'
           filter: '(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))'
```

But when I try to login getting error message as:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, 
comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1d
    eption is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, 
comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]
            at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191)
```

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 49/52e seems to indicate invalid credentials, reference [here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes#gsc.tab=0)

Indicates an Active Directory (AD) AcceptSecurityContext error, which is returned when the username is valid but the combination of password and user credential is invalid. This is the AD equivalent of LDAP error code 49.